# How to write select SQL to use like when using control parameter?

Tags: asp.net

1. How to change to use like instead of = ?

([Card_no] = @Search)

1. Moreover, if i want to show all in default, this method force to user to type 
   something first. How to show all in default when using control parameter?

   ```
   SelectCommand="SELECT [Serial_no], [Transaction_Date], [Card_no], [Company],[IsCredit], [Fee] FROM [CarPark] WHERE ([Card_no] = @Search) or ([Company] = @Search)"
   UpdateCommand="UPDATE [CarPark] SET
   Card_no=@Card_no,
   Company=@Company, 
   IsCredit=@IsCredit,
   Fee=@Fee
   WHERE Serial_no=@Serial_no">
   <UpdateParameters>
       <asp:Parameter Name="Card_no" Type="String" />
       <asp:Parameter Name="Company" Type="String" />
       <asp:Parameter Name="IsCredit" Type="Boolean" />
           <asp:Parameter Name="Fee" Type="Double" />
       </UpdateParameters>
       <SelectParameters>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Search_TextBox" DefaultValue="" Name="Search" 
               PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
   </SelectParameters>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Card_no like '%{0}%'

Or if you must use named parameters:

Card_no like '%'+@search +'%'